# Show that $\binom{2n}{n}+\binom{2n}{ n-1} = {1\over2}\binom{2n+2}{n+1}$

Tags: combinatorics

Show that $$\binom{2n}{n}+\binom{2n}{n-1} = {1\over2}\binom{2n+2}{n+1}$$ I'm guessing you're supposed to use combinatoric arguments to prove it.

I really don't know how to interpret the right-hand side of the equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose we want to pick $n+1$ numbers from $1,2, \dots, 2n+2$. There are $\binom{2n+2}{n+1}$ ways.

Alternatively, condition on the first two, and the cases are:

1. $1$ and $2$ are both chosen. Then there are $\binom{2n}{n-1}$ ways to choose the remaining numbers.
2. Just $1$ or just $2$ are chosen. Then there are $\binom{2n}{n}$ ways (each) to choose the remaining numbers.
3. Neither $1$ nor $2$ are chosen. Then there are $\binom{2n}{n+1} = \binom{2n}{n-1}$ ways to choose the remaining numbers.

Therefore, $\binom{2n+2}{n+1} = 2\left(\binom{2n}{n-1} + \binom{2n}{n}\right)$

Answer (score 1):

HINT: You can do it entirely algebraically.

$$\binom{2n+2}{n+1}=\frac{(2n+2)!}{(n+1)!^2}=\frac{2n+2}{n+1}\cdot\frac{(2n+1)!}{n!(n+1)}=2\binom{?}{?}$$

For a combinatorial approach, imagine that you have $2n+1$ white balls and one red one. There are $\binom{2n+2}{n+1}$ ways to choose $n+1$ of these balls, and exactly half of those ways include the red ball. Now we want to interpret $\binom{2n}n+\binom{2n}{n-1}$ as the number of ways to choose the red ball and $n$ white balls. If you’re allowed to employ Pascal’s identity to simplify this sum, it’s pretty straightforward; otherwise you could incorporate a combinatorial proof of Pascal’s identity in the remainder of the argument.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm supposed to, since the university course I'm taking emphasizes using combinatoric arguments or the binomial theorem to prove such statements.

Comment: @sucksatmath: I’ve added a combinatorial approach. (I approve of the course emphasis, by the way: combinatorial arguments are often the most informative.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the identity
$$
\binom{n}{k}+\binom{n}{k-1}=\binom{n+1}{k}
$$
to simplify the LHS
and the identity
$$
\binom{n+1}{k+1}={n+1\over k+1}\binom{n}{k}
$$
to simplify the RHS.

Answer (score 0):

Just using Pascal's recurrence,
$$\textstyle
  \binom{2n+2}{n+1}
=\binom{2n+1}{n}+\binom{2n+1}{n+1}
=\binom{2n}{n-1}+2\binom{2n}{n}+\binom{2n}{n+1}
=2\Bigl(\binom{2n}{n-1}+\binom{2n}{n}\Bigr).
$$
Now divide both sides by $2$. Since there is an easy combinatorial explanation for Pascal's recurrence, you can easily deduce one for the resulting identity.